# Check multiple props with Styled-Components

Tags: javascript, styled-components

With styled-components, I am able to check if a boolean prop is `true`, then add css like below:

```
const Box = styled.div`
  ${({ someProp }) =>
    someProp &&
    css`
      border: none;
  `};
`
```

But what if I want to check multiple conditions? For instance, I want to check if `someProp` is `true` AND `someOtherProp` is `false`, how would I go about doing that?

I'm thinking doing something like this but syntax does not appear to be correct:

```
const Box = styled.div`
  ${({ someProp, someOtherProp }) =>
    someProp && !someOtherProp
    css`
      border: 1px solid red;
  `};
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const Box = styled.div`
  ${({ someProp, someOtherProp }) =>
    someProp && !someOtherProp &&
    css`
      border: 1px solid red;
  `};
```